# What is the proper method for enabling MSSQL support in Laravel homestead?

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, laravel

I've seen a lot of people talking about FreeTDS and Sybase drivers, but I can't seem to figure out what I need to enable laravel/php access to MSSQL databases from a Linux Web Server running the Laravel Homestead Vagrant box.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm resurrecting this because it was one of the early results on google for my problem...

First, ssh into your box `vagrant ssh` from the Homestead folder.

Then, install php5-mssql
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install php5-mssql`

For newer Vagrant with PHP 7, use `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install php7.0-sybase`.

If this fails, you may need to do `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Now edit freetds.conf `sudo vi /etc/freetds/freetds.conf`

Change the top few lines:

```
[global]
        # TDS protocol version
        tds version = 7.2
        client charset = UTF-8
```

Finally you should create a locales.conf file within /etc/freetds to allow correct parsing of dates with SQL Server, i have this configuration and has worked well with DateTime, DateTime2, SmallDateTime and Date data types: `sudo vi /etc/freetds/locales.conf`

```
[default]
    date format = %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%z

[en_US]
    date format = %b %e %Y %I:%M:%S:%z%p
    language = us_english
    charset = iso_1

[es_ES]
    date format = %b %d %Y %I:%M%p
    language = spanish
    charset = iso_1

[pt_BR]
    date format = %d/%m/%Y %H:%M
    language = Portuguese
    charset = iso_1

[it_IT]
    date format = %d/%m/%Y %H:%M
    language = Italiano
    charset = iso_1
```

Last, restart your server `vagrant halt && vagrant up`  (Just restarting nginx doesn't cause the settings to take effect.)

Source: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/sqlsrv-driver-on-linux/replies/14887

Comment: I hear that this is the "proper" way and that I shouldn't have selected the other answer. Why use this method and configure freetds when installing the sybase package seems to do the trick?

Comment: sybase and mssql are both used to install freetds, the two can be synonymous (php5-sybase and php5-mssql install the same package).  If you don't edit the config files, you get some funky results in some cases (ie long column names or datetime fields).  My package instructions are for PHP5 and the current version of vagrant is PHP7 so the new command may need to be php7.0-sybase in the install, but I'd need someone to verify that as my company is still on PHP 5.6 so I haven't upgraded.

Comment: I followed the instructions above but I am still getting an error when trying to connect to MSSQL using sqlsrv_connect(). Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Simple:
First, ssh into your box vagrant ssh from the Homestead folder.

Command : vagrant ssh 
We need to install the Sybase package for enabling the support for PDO and Mssql.
Command : sudo apt-get install php7.0-sybase